# Is there a way to get build metadata from CMake?

Tags: c++, build, compilation, cmake

I have a project that I build with CMake. I'd like to be able to do something like:

`cmake .. --generate-metadata`

Ideally this would create an output file which describes what CMake is about to do. Something like what was described in [this email to the CMake mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=cmake-developers@cmake.org&q=subject:%22Re%3A%20%5Bcmake-developers%5D%20Extracting%20target%20metadata%2C%20IDE%20integration%22&o=newest):

```
[
   "name" : "testc1"
   "sources" : ["foo.cpp", "bar.cpp"]
   "defines" : ["BUILD_TEST=1", "QT_CORE_LIB"]
   "includes" : ["/opt/bat/include", "/usr/include/qt5"]
   "extraDefines" : {
     "foo.cpp" : ["EXTRA_FOO=1"]
   }
]
```

After reading that email post, I don't think this is a native part of CMake yet. [CMake generators](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) seem like they could be the ticket here, but it doesn't seem like I can specify a new generator at runtime? Can generators be plugged in via some API/SDK/tooling, or do they need to be compiled in?

Comment: What do you mean when you said "create an output file which describes what CMake is about to do"? Because, maybe I didn't quite get what you asking for, but there's a file in "${put_your_build_dir_here}/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log" with some information about your build data. See if that file is what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON` argument is exactly what I needed.